# Reverse a string using recursion works in C, but not in C++

Tags: c++, c, recursion, reverse

This is the code I've written for reversing a string using recursion.

I have tried it in 2 ways:

- One with C
- One with C++

The C version works as expected but, when I used the C++ version it doesn't give any output and continuously reads input.

```
void reverse() // C++ version
{
    char ch;
    cin>>ch;
    if(ch!='\n')reverse();
    cout<<ch;
}
void reverse() // C version
{
    char ch;
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    if(ch!='\n')reverse();
    printf("%c",ch);
}
int main(void)
{
    reverse();

    return 0;
}
```

What is the problem with the C++ code?

Comment: 1. The code above won't compile because you define two different functions of the same type. 2. It's not clear what your question is; try be more specific.

Comment: aree i didn't use 2 funcion at a time :/ i just pasted it here to ask

Comment: @pufi you use scanf("%c",&ch); which reads a character, then how are you trying to reverse it since it is only one?

Comment: but c version works well . so whats the problem with c++ version?

Comment: @pufi `cin>>ch;` won't read space character (For example newline). Study about `cin.get`, `cin.getchar`, and [`cin.read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `cin>>ch` won't read a whitespace character. Instead you can use [`cin.get`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/).

Like:

```
std::cin.get (ch);
```

---

As @MohitJain Said, you can use `cin.read` also.

Comment: i cant :( i have not enough reputation to vote . sry

Comment: Why use a string in this case? Wouldn't the OP's code work just by changing `cin>>ch` to `cin.get(ch);`?

Comment: And shouldn't "_won't read a space_" be "won't read a whitespace character"?

Comment: @CoolGuy, well the problem is that the OP wants to read a string, as mentioned in the title, but instead is trying to read a character. The OP doesn't know that mistake. Also, reversing a character would be the character itself, so it doesn't make any sense reversing a character. Yes that would compile successfully, but still the user running the program will only be able to enter a character, not a string or word.

Comment: @CoolGuy, see my edit, I've edited the white space thing.

Comment: The OP is reversing a string by reading in characters (until a `\n`) recursively. Try the code and you'll understand.

Comment: @CoolGuy, that's totally my mistake. I did not notice that the calling of the  function using recursion. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

In your C++ `reverse()`, Use `cin.get(ch);` instead of `cin>>ch;` as the latter won't read `\n`.